# Outlook 2007 meeting request varying times across users

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, time-zone, meeting-request

I've googled this quite a bit, but none of the answers seem to apply to me.

User A creates a meeting and invites everyone to a meeting at 1:30pm. Everyone gets the meeting for 1:30pm except User B who gets it for 2:30pm. User B responds with a "Correction" for 1:30pm and it shows up to User A for 12:30pm.

I've checked Time Zone settings both in Windows Time and Date settings and also in Outlook options for both computers involved. Also, the DST check boxes are all checked (4x).

I'm not sure what else to check. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with server improper time policies on my network (that I didn't set up). She was getting her time from the wrong DC.

Answer (score 2):

i have seen in earlier versions of Outlook where i had to remove the check mark for the check for daylight savings time in Outlook itself (seems like it double minused an hour for some reason) to get it to sync up correctly.  This seemed to correct itself with the last daylight savings time "hotfixes" we applied.

Comment: Thanks for input. It would be hard to troubleshoot this because both users are never in their office and it isn't off by an hour with every appointment. Didn't know that when they originally brought it to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the time zone from Outlook? They need to be the same for both user, if not, it's normal that they do not see the same meeting time (From Outlook 2010):
[image: This is from Outlook 2010]

Comment: Did it work or you still have issues?

Comment: As mentioned in the original post I checked Time Zones in Windows and Outlook.